# Counterexamples in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, book-recommendation

Can you suggest me a book which primarily deals with counter-examples in measure theory?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this book?

Gary L. Wise and Eric B. Hall, [**Counterexamples in Probability and Real Analysis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195070682), Oxford University Press, 1993, xii + 211 pages.